# Как понять какие изображения из интернета можно использовать в своей игре?

Tags: разработка-игр, авторские-права

Есть идея создать аниме пазлы на андроид и залить игры в play market, но сразу же встал вопрос об авторских правах на скачанные из интернета изображения аниме. Как мне поступить в такой ситуации?

Comment: Все достаточно просто. Нет явного разрешения автора - не берите? Авторство вызывает сомнения - не берите.

Answer (score 1):

Авторские права нарушены, если не согласовано использование материалов с их автором.

> Как понять ... ?

Спросить у автора.

Более глобальный ответ: существует ряд открытых материалов для компьютерных игр публикуемых сразу с информацией о их использовании. Специализированные порталы для разработчиков, дизйнеров, музыкантов позволяют публиковать свои материалы как на свободных основаниях, так и продавать материалы.

Вот статья нашлась в поиске
https://pikabu.ru/story/16_zamechatelnyikh_saytov_s_besplatnoy_grafikoy_dlya_razrabotchikov_igr_3903473